# Drawing Text with Text Kit and *not* UITextView

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview, textkit

I'm looking at TextKit and every tutorial I've come across gives me the same information:

`NSTextStorage` holds your string and font information, [`NSLayoutManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/) manages layout and glyphs, and `NSTextContainer` specifies areas that the text should be drawn to.

Then, the next step is always UITextView. What if I want to draw the glyphs myself? How might I go about doing that? How does UITextView do it? Do I need to drop down to Core Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `NSLayoutManager` has some handy drawing methods that you can use. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000371-SW44) describes them. The simplest one is `drawBackgroundForGlyphRange(_:atPoint:)` which draws into a text container.